# Accessing an already installed application's database from my own application

Tags: android, database-connection

Could anyone tell me if I can access an existing database, not directly owned by that my application is using please?

My code works fine for accessing a database created at runtime by my application but fails with the following error:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
null

I read that Android security prevents access by checking the application ID (PID)?  I have not written the application of the database I need to access/change data of.

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot. On rooted devices you can access every location if you elevate your rights to root.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Content Providers, if the app provides this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

No you can not access other apps db. The databse file is stored in /data/data/yourpackage.yourapp/database. On a non rooted phone you can not even have access of filesystem here,  on Rooted phone am not sure if u can do it or not.

If you want to share data with other applications  or access other apps database you have content providers for this purpose read [content provider docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, normally you can't do that!